# Nowhere Monotonic/ Differentiable function proof

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, monotone-functions

I got stuck trying to prove that:

1. $T(x)$ is nowhere monotonic
2. $T(x)$ is nowhere differentiable

$$f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ f(x)= |x|\quad \text{for} \quad\frac{-1}{2}\le x\le \frac{1}{2} \quad \text{and $f$ is periodic with period $1$}$$

$$\text{for }n =0,1,2,...\quad f_n(x):=\frac{f(4^n x)}{4^n}$$

$$T(x):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n (x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{f(4^n x)}{4^n}\right)$$

Comment: what is $f(x)$ outside of $[-1/2;1/2]$ ?

Comment: Thanks, I just added that

Comment: The best hint I can give you is to imagine what's going on, try to imagine how $T$ looks like and understand why it is constructed that way. (Even after you do this, you will have a lot of technical work to do, but at least you know what you should do)

Comment: That's what it looks like https://www.google.ch/search?q=takagi+function&rlz=1C1CHMO_itCH584CH584&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi39NnKqpbZAhVF7RQKHY_cC_0Q_AUICigB&biw=1920&bih=974#imgrc=-VIxcIUtyLSEuM:

Comment: I still have no idea ahaha

Comment: @AndreaTettamanti Searching online for how it looks is the worst thing you could do... now you have no idea why it looks that way, draw $f(x)$, then draw $f_1(x)$ and then draw $f(x)+f_1(x)$ try to find out on which interval they're monotone, and where they're differentiable.

Comment: @yanko I'll try that

Comment: Hint: by change of variables you have that $f_n(x)=|x|$ on the interval $[-1/2\cdot 1/4^n , 1/2\cdot 1/4^n]$ and it is periodic of period $1/4^n$.

Comment: Thanks @yanko, with that i know that for all x in R x is a point where a period for some fn(x) ends, but now how do I proove that T(x) is nowhere monotonic?

Comment: @AndreaTettamanti this is not completely true. Also I would start with part (b) as it's a little bit easier. Notice that $f(x)$ at $....-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3....$, similarly, $f_n$ is not differentiable at $....,-2/4^n,-1/4^n,0,1/4^n,2/4^n,....$. so the set of all $k/4^n$ is the set of your "bad points" and it is a dense set this should imply that the infinite sum is nowhere differentiable (some ugly and technical epsilon delta arguments). For nowhere monotone just do the same, check on which intervals the sequence is monotone. This is so annoying and I prefer not to write down a solution.